# Visual Studio 2012 web deploy InvalidParameter: index

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012, msdeploy, webdeploy

When trying to publish a website to a server from Visual Studio 2012 on a remote desktop (Windows Server 2012), this error pops up:

```
------ Publish started: Project: <project name>, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Error: InvalidParameter
Parameter name: index
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

It also appears if I don't enter a password in the connection tab of the publish dialog and press Start preview on the Preview tab. This suggests it is a local problem, not a server one.

Publishing to the same website does work when logged in with another account on the remote desktop, and it also works with my publishing credentials on this account. So it is not a problem with my publishing credentials.

The publishing settings are identical, "validate connection" in the Connection tab works when I enter my password.

We have looked into IIS settings, but it appears all settings are correct. Searching on Google shows a couple of people with the same error, but without a solution except for copying everything to a new project, which is not an option in this case.

We have completely removed the project from Visual Studio and reloaded it from TFS, we did a rebuild, which works fine. Debugging the website in Internet Explorer works fine (from Visual Studio) as well.

We do not have a clue what this error means or what causes it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this problem for three weeks, I have found the solution.

For future generations: the problem was due to PHPTools, the plug-in we use for the development. We were using a version that was 1.5 years old, updating the plug-in has solved the problem. Such a foolish problem, we have spent way too many hours on this.